# How to hookup an InSinkErator hot water dispenser to a Waterstone Hot/Cold Faucet

Tags: plumbing, hot-water, kitchen-sink

I'm trying to figure out what to do with the 3rd connector on my InSinkErator H-CONTOUR-SS.  I have a WaterStone hot/cold filtration faucet model 1400HC-SS that doesn't have a connection for that 3rd connector.

I contacted both WaterStone and InSinkErator and both had equally useless advice. Basically InSinkErator said I have to buy a faucet from them.  And WaterStone said I have to buy a hot water dispenser from them. Horrible customer service on both sides.

So I'm hoping I'm not the 1st person to want to do this and somebody can tell me what to do with that 3rd connector.

Thank You

Comment: These companies make faucets and water heaters that are deigned to be used together.  There is not a standard for them to follow, and they are under no obligation to support each others products.  Also, to clear up your question - you have a tank from Insinkerator and a facuet from Waterstone?  The manual for the insinkerator tank shows three connections, and the manual for the waterstone faucet shows three tubes.  So whats the issue?

Comment: InSinkErator [manual](https://insinkerator.emerson.com/documents/installation-care-use-manual-en-us-1567736.pdf), and the WaterStone [manual](http://www.waterstonefaucetsintl.com/install-guides/Waterstone-Filtration-Faucet-install-guide.pdf), as far as I can tell from the model numbers given...